# How to sort ArrayList(int)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sorting, arraylist

How can I sort the `Arraylist` in  ascending and descending orders.
Example.

```
ArrayList list= new ArrayList();
list.Add(2);
list.Add(8);
list.Add(0);
list.Add(1);
```

How can I sort the above list in both ascending and descending order?

Comment: That's not valid C# code (Add, not add). Why are you using the non-generic ArrayList type anyway? Are you using .NET 1.1 for some reason?

Comment: Ya. list.add(). that is wrong only sorry for that.I want to sort the arraylist since i'm dynamically adding the values in codebehind.Can u suggest someother collection which supports sorting

Comment: No, you mean `list.Add`. `ArrayList` has *always* been sortable, but without knowing why you're using a non-generic type rather than the rather nice `List<T>` it's hard to advise you well.

Comment: Another question is, probably: what type of sort do you expect? Since each element is an object, do you want them compared as strings, or numerically?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list.Sort()` for ascending order. For descending order, you need to reverse the order by implementing `IComparer`. Something like this will do:

```
// calling normal sort:
ArrayList ascendingList = list.Sort();

// calling reverse sort:
ArrayList descendingList = list.Sort(new ReverseSort());

// implementation:
public class ReverseSort : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        // reverse the arguments
        return Comparer.Default.Compare(y, x);
    }

}
```

Note that, like Jon Skeet mentions in the comment thread under the main question, you do not need to use the untyped ArrayList at all. Instead, you can use the generic `List<T>`, which is typesafe and is simply more versatile.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList contains a Sort method. (Edited to remove incorrect .NET information)

Comment: Can you explain me briefly or can u provide me any link

Comment: See this page for documentation of the ArrayList class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx There you can find information on the Sort method.  You will have to implement a comparator to sort in ASC vs DSC, however examples are provided in the documentation of this.

Comment: It's contained a Sort method since 1.0 - certainly in 1.1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/895sadkk(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use list.Sort() function.
see example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0e743hdt.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can you use [ArrayList.Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using an array list instead of `List<int>` here is dangerous, however, here is what you are looking for:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList al = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
al.Add(5);
al.Add(3);
al.Add(1);
al.Add(4);
al.Add(0);
al.Sort();

foreach (var x in al)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
}

al.Sort(new DescendingIntSorter());

foreach (var x in al)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
}



public class DescendingIntSorter : System.Collections.IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return ((int)y).CompareTo((int)x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

list.Sort() will sort them but I would suggest using List<> and Collections for sorting.  Avoid using ArrayList imo.

Answer (score 0):

With the ascending list, you can use list.Sort()

And the for the descending list, there's an easy way to do it!

You can do descending lists like this:

```
list.Sort();
list.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void DisplayMain()
    {
        string sValue = "1,2,5,8,6,7,110,220";
        txtValue.Text = sValue;
        string[] asDS = sValue.Split(',');
        ArrayList alData = new ArrayList();
        foreach (string sDS in asDS)
        {
            alData.Add(sDS);
        }//end of foreach
        alData.Sort(new IntSort());
        //============
        int iCnt = 0;
        StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string sData in alData)
        {
            iCnt++;
            sbResult.AppendLine(iCnt.ToString() + " ====> " + sData);
        }//end of if 
        string sResult = sbResult.ToString();
        txtResult.Text = sResult;
    }//end of DisplayMain

    public class IntSort : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            string sX = x.ToString();
            string sY = y.ToString();
            int iResult = 0;
            int iX = int.Parse(sX);
            int iY = int.Parse(sY);
            if(iX > iY) { iResult = 1; }//end of if
            else if (iY > iX) { iResult = -1; }//end of if 
            return iResult;
            //return ((int)y).CompareTo((int)x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).