# How do I sort an array from smallest to biggest?

Tags: c#

I have stored my ArrayList into a multidimensional array to be displayed on the richtextbox.
How do I sort an ArrayList/multidimensional array from the smallest value to the biggest and be displayed on rtbx?

The variables are initialized as:

```
public static ArrayList dataList = new ArrayList();
public static float[,] finalData = new float[superX.var, 8];
```

superX.var is int 72.

Comment: Any reason you're still using `ArrayList`, seven years after generic collections were introduced?

Comment: My senior developed the program using ArrayList. All I have to do is to improve and add in other features into the program. I had to learn C# in less than 7 months on my own, so I am not sure of any new features/functions on C#.

Comment: Have u seen this?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6695364/1380061
That said, when Jon Skeet tells you a piece of good advice. Take it! =).

Comment: @user1796001: I'm not sure what you mean by "your senior" - but you should probably inform them about `List<T>`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort ArrayList(int)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695295/how-to-sort-arraylistint)

Answer (score 2):

If possible, instead of the **deprecated ArrayList**, you should use a List object (in the System.Collections.Generic namespace). The List object has sort methods in which you can specify the sort using a Lambda expression, or you can use LINQ (since it implements IEnumerable)

Using a Lambda expression to order by descending:

```
var dataListSorted = dataList.OrderByDescending(x => x.PropertyName);
```